# Read non regular time format from excel in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I am trying to read non regular time format from excel in C#, the time value in excel is as "29-Aug-01 11.23.00.000000000 PM", and in excel the cells format is 'regular' not 'time'.

Now I need read the time in excel then assign the time into calendar time in asp.net/c#, how can I let the program understand the time format?

Big thx!

my code does not work

```
DateTime expTime = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, "dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.fffffffff tt",      System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have similar solution, but more accur.

```
string s = "29-Aug-01 11.23.00.000000000 AM";

DateTimeOffset myDate = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(
    s,
    "dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.fffffff00 tt",
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

EDIT:
You can't use more then 7 'f' chars.

Comment: +1, this is definitely more accurate and I guess the the OP has to deal with considering first 7 digits for milliseconds.

Comment: Thx! It works! output is "8/29/2001 11:23:00 AM -04:00", what is the "-04:00"? Time zone? what can I do if I need display at least the milliseconds or nanoseconds?

Comment: @Windtalker what output? You haven't showed any code that outputs or formats the result. If you use Console.WriteLine or String.Format without specifying a format, the current user's date format will be used. In this case it looks like the US format is used.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos the output is "8/29/2001 11:23:00 AM -04:00", what if I want to have the milliseconds in the output? You may have a look at my example in the first post. thx

Answer (score 0):

The original format string fails because the DateTime type can't represent nanoseconds. The following format string will work:

```
var expTime = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, "dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.fffffff00 tt", 
              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This works because the `00` characters are interpreted as literals and ignored during parsing.

Note that I'm passing `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` instead of the system's UI Culture. This ensures that the English month abbreviations will be used even if the user's UI Culture is set to another language. Otherwise, `DateTime.ParseExact` will try to parse the date string using the user's language month abbreviations